# java exception: No such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, permissions, java, filesystem, webserver

I am trying to run a GATE application via jetty web application server in Ubuntu. I am getting

```
java.io.IOException: 

error=2,
```

No such file or directory because of a particular GATE plugin (MultiPaX) which is trying to access "minipar.linux" located in

```
WEB-INF/gate-files/application-resources/Parser_Minipar/minipar.linux
```

I have set read and write permissions to this file and directory, as well as allowing executing the file as a program. I get a Permission Denied error, when disallowing program execution.  I have set all directories containing the file +x via chmod -R 755 /all/directories/up/to/file/

Is this a file permission problem? or could there be another cause?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a "Permission Denied" error, it'd definitely a permissions error.
Try `chmod 666` and see if that fixes it. That gives everyone read/write access.
You don't want to open it up like that though, so if it does fix it, then `chown` the file to the user who is running Jetty and `chmod` it back to 644.

To find the user running Jetty:

```
ps aux | grep jetty
```

To change ownership of the file:

```
chown jettyuser.jettyuser /path/to/file
```

Comment: Unfortunately chmod 666 didn't work. The error is now java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied. I am completely stuck..

Comment: The user running jetty is root and changing ownership has no effect..